# Как получить id записи базы данных из ComboBox?

Tags: c++, c++builder

В форме есть `ComboBox`. Он заполняется из базы данных списком покупателей. При этом, если пользователь выбирает покупателя, в "гриде" отображаются его история покупок. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе значения из `ComboBox` можно было каким то образом узнать `id` записи покупателя в базе данных? Т.е. выбрал в `ComboBox` покупателя, после чего пошел запрос в БД по `id` этого покупателя и отобразился в "гриде".

Не уверен, что будет работать `ComboBox->ItemIndex`, ведь при формировании `ComboBox`'a они выставляются по порядку и могут не совпадать с индексами базы данных. Выборку по текстовому полю ФИО покупателя делать тоже не хочется, т.к. возникнут проблемы с однофамильцами.

**Обновление**

Надо как то применить AddObject. Объекты я добавил в ComboBox. Вопрос теперь - как их вытащить?

```
ComboBox2->Items->AddObject(IBQuery1->FieldByName("price_group_name")->AsString,
IBQuery1->FieldByName("price_group_id"));`
```

Надо как то вытащить их `Caption`:

```
Label6->Caption = ComboBox2->Items->Objects[ComboBox2->ItemIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать не TComboBox а TDBLookupCombo, который напрямую берет строки из TDataSet

Comment: Обновил вопрос.